# Responsive position: absolute and relative

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I have a problem with responsive navigation I have .toggle which when opened unfolds and it turns out the menu when I give .toggle position: relative; ul: position absolute;, everything works fine except my adaptive width , I need pos : relative; to the menu which appears does not affect the page!!

With position

```css
@media screen and (max-width:1199px) {
  /* Responsive menu */
  nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
 }
 ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
 }
 ul li {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  background: #333333;
 }
 ul li:hover {
  background-color: #242424;
  transition: all 0.7s;
 }
 .toggle {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block; 
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
 }
 .active {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="background_header overlay">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-ms-2 col-xs-2">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logotype" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-3">
          <nav>
            <div class="toggle hidden-lg">
              <i class="fa fa-bars nav" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ex1">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ex2">Expertise</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ex3">Teams</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ex4">Works</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ex5">People say</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ex6">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
          <h1>We Are Awesome Creative Agency</h1>
          <p class="header_description">
            This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet
            mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
          </p>
          <button type="submit" class="header_button">
                            <span class="content_button header_content_button">Learn More</span>
                        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvxwX.png)

[Screenshot my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLeA3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found answer I give my body `position:relative; and ul {
left:50%; 
margin-left:-50%;
}`
It is works, thanks for watching!!!